# Multi-Monitoring in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am working in Visual Studio 2010. The main feature of VS 2010 is Multi-Monitering. How to do that. I am having 2 systems (CRT, 17 inches). I had opened my appliction, by right clicking the tab, i got the FLOAT option.That particular screen comes seperately, i had draged to the edge of my system, but the screen is not shared to my next system. Whether any Specific Configuration needed for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Have you tried dragging the tab you want to show up on the second monitor onto it?**

Clicking and dragging the tab out of the group will automatically undock it and allow you to move it around wherever you want. This works the same way as you would move any other window to your second display, like in Windows Explorer.

**Are both monitors recognized and supported by Windows?**

Remember that you must to have Windows itself configured to recognize and work with multiple displays in order for these features in VS 2010 to work. Check your "Display" control panel and make sure that it shows two screens in the correct physical configuration, and that both are enabled (the "Extend my Windows desktop onto this monitor" option must be checked).

It's also hard to tell from your question if both of the monitors that you want to use are connected to the same physical machine. VS 2010's multiple monitor support is not going to let you move windows onto a screen connected to a different physical computer without the aid of some [third-party utility](http://www.maxivista.com/).